# Is it possible to create wrong Regular expression in ActionScript/Flex which will cause runtime error?

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript

Is it possible to create wrong Regular expression in ActionScript/Flex which will cause runtime error? I've tried so many weird regexpes in Flex and Flex never complained! How do I know If my regexp valid?

Answer (score 3):

In theory, according to the [ActionScript 3.0 SyntaxError documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/SyntaxError.html), when a regular expression cannot be parsed a SyntaxError is generated at runtime that you can detect in a try/catch block.

In practice, I've never actually seen the RegExp class exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have ActionScript/Flex, so I can't test this. Since you haven't given any examples, I don't know what you think is a "weird" regex. What happens if you try one of these:

```
/(?<=x*)foo/
```

(ECMAScript regexes don't support lookbehind)

```
/foo([/
```

(missing closing parentheses/brackets)

```
/foo)]/
```

(missing opening parentheses/brackets)

```
/foo(?)/
```

(Syntax error)

```
/foo\1/
```

(invalid backreference)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But actually none of those listed Regexpes giving me an error! and _regExp = new RegExp(pattern,options); creates an instance of RegExp, where _regExp.source is populated with exactly same stuff in pattern?! Puzzling, eh?

Answer (score 1):

If your end goal is to determine whether a particular regular expression is valid or not then I'm not sure trying to intentionally generate runtime errors is the best way to accomplish that.

Instead I would recommend testing your patterns against known inputs and make sure they behave as intended.  You can use a tool like this to test:
[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: Thank you, but given tool displays same behavior similar to my Flex experience - therefore useless for testing wrong regular expressions listed by Tim and for any other wrong expressions as well...